# Как обрезать изображение после поворота?

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Здравствуйте!
Школьная программа совсем забыта :(
Вот картинка для понимания задачи (изображение может быть не только квадратом, но и прямоугольником)):
[image: картинка для понимания задачи (изображение может быть не только квадратом, но и прямоугольником)]

Имеем изображение (жёлтый прямоугольник), которое мы поворачиваем (зелёный прямоугольник). Необходимо обрезать его по красному прямоугольнику =)
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно узнать отступ (h) для обрезания картинки что бы "исключить" пустое место, если мне известны только высота жёлтого прямоугольника и угол наклона?

Заранее благодарен :)

Comment: Угол в "треугольнике" a/2 , h и третей стороны будет равен углу поворота. Тогда скорее всего высота будет равна `h = a/ (2 tg alpha)` (это грубо с погрешностью на квадрат).

Comment: Вопрос, а зачем? Просто проэцируете точки в новую "матрицу" `M2 ( fx(x,y) , fy(x,y) ) = M1(x,y)` - и ничего вычислять не нужно. Сами лягут куда нужно. Только "центр" поворота нужно правильно выставить.

Comment: @nick_n_a, т.е. мне нужно использовать формулу `h = a / (2*tg b)`, где a - это высота прямоугольника, а b - угол поворота?
Нужно это для php скрипта)
Не представляю как пользоваться матрицами в php x_X

Comment: a - это длинна верхней грани, она же сторона треугольника, ваша h - это другая сторона которая прямой угос с h, а третья сторона это повёрнутая грань, образующая угол b с а. Да, эта формула даст вам на процентов 99 правильный результат. это "упрощённый" результат, который не учитывает поведение более маленького треугольника, который одной гранью совпадёт с этим. Если ваша задача требует большей точности - нужно сидеть вырисовывать, потом высчитывать.

Answer (score 0):

1)
Найти yE  подставив x(D) в уравнение прямой по двум точкам:

```
y=y1+(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x-x1)
yE = y(A) +(y(B)-y(A))/(x(B)-x(A))*(x(D)-x(A))
E(x(D),yE)
```

Отразить E относительно центра зеленого прямоугольника получить F.

```
F(-x(D),-yE)
G(x(E),y(F))
H(x(F),y(E))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Если нужно чтобы искомый 4 угольник касался всех красных отрезков
 то наверно это оптимизация на 1 переменную.
Задать положение A1 например как кривая безье 1 ст.(фиолетов точка).
Искать такой t чтобы:
Нужные точки касались красных отрезков а зеленая точка была минимально далеко от своего отрезка(расстояние от точки до прямой) =).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]